# Pegar o url da primeira imagem de cada post (div), armazenar essa url em uma variável

Tags: jquery, css, imagem, div, blogger

Tenho um blog, e para cada postagem é criada automaticamente uma div. Na página inicial deve ser exibida apenas a primeira imagem do post e o título (com link) referente a postagem. Só que aqui, gostaria que a imagem ficasse definida como `background-image` de sua div pai.

Para isso, uso a uma tag do blogger que retorna o id único para aquela postagem, gerado pelo próprio blogger.

Com o id da div, utilizo o seletor `:first-child` para pegar a primeira imagem, e sucessivamente o url dela, armazenando em uma variável, para depois utilizar na definição do css `background-image`. Assim como mostra no código:

```
$(window).load(
    $(function pegaId(id){
            var idDoPost = $("#"+id).attr("id");
                console.log(idDoPost);

            var imagemUrl = document.querySelector("#" + idDoPost + " img").src;
            console.log(imagemUrl);

            $(".post-outer").css("background-image", "url("+imagemUrl+")");

            pegaId("ident<data:post.id/>"); /*chama a função pegaId e passa como parametro o id
                                            que será utilizado para identificar a div*/

}));
```

O problema é que já mudei o código várias vezes, usei outros seletores, acrescentei mais funções, mudei o código de posição na página e nada.

Pesquiso por soluções mas também não encontro.

No console diz que o url das imagens estão "undefined", acho que é porque as imagens só são carregadas depois, mesmo utilizando o `$(document).ready()` ou `$(window).load()`.

Queria que alguém me ajudasse, pois quero fazer um código que pegue essas imagens automaticamente.

Comment: Se escreves-te `url` em vez de `src` errado corrige pf na pergunta... de onde vais buscar `"ident<data:post.id/>"`?

Comment: Então, dentro do Blogger a tags próprias do sistema que retornam um id distinto para cada postagem... assim não há 2 postagens com um mesmo id. Dessa forma a primeira imagem também será diferente. Aqui há um exemplo de como o a tag gera um número **<div class="postagens" id="ident696899985754861576">**. Podem observar que "ident" continua o mesmo, mas o "<data:post.id/>" virá um código de números único.

Comment: Poderia pegar id por id, e para cada um, pegar a url de cada imagem e aplicar como background da sua div pai, em vez de usar estas tags do blogger? E como fazer?

Comment: Você está chamando a função pegaId dentro dela mesmo, por quê?

Comment: Não sei... eu já tentei de tudo... coloquei a chamada dentro dela mesmo porque era a única que durante as mudanças me retornava algo. Se coloco a chamada antes diz que a função 'pegaId' não está declarada, se coloco depois 'function(id)' não retorna nada... mudando o código de posição essa foi realmente a única que me retornou o 'id' no 'console'. Por isso deixei assim.

Comment: Oi Italo, não trabalhe com tentativa e erro, as coisas acabam ficando mais difíceis ;)

Vamos lá, separe os blocos, primeiro, escreva o bloco de $(window).load, fora dele crie sua função e volte para o $(window).load e faça a chamada, algo assim:

`$(window).load (
    suaFuncao();
)

function suaFuncao() {
    return 'foo';
}`

Answer (score 1):

supondo que cada div de uma postagem tenha a class "post":

```js
$(function() {
    var urlsImagens = $(".post img:nth-child(1)").map(function() {
       return this.getAttribute("src");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(
    $(function pegaId(id){

            var imagemUrl = document.querySelector(".post-body img:nth-child(1)").src;
            console.log(imagemUrl);

            $("body").css("background-image", "url("+imagemUrl+")");

}));
```